# SSH Port closed although forwarded correctly

Tags: ssh, firewall, port-forwarding, ports

I'm having an issue with opening my SSH port. Here are the symptoms.

- Within the local network I can ssh to the machine, including both locally (ssh localhost) and from alternate computers.
- I have correctly port forwarded the incoming connections to the LAN IP.
- On the local machine I can nmap the LAN IP address and see port 22 open. I can also nmap the WAN IP address and see port 22 open, along with other services on the router.
- I can ssh the WAN IP from the local machine.

However -

- From external  machines, I cannot see port 22 as open (examined via nmap)
- Sites such as can you see me are reporting port 22 is closed (connection timeout) from the local computer.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and do not have any intermediate firewalls present.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some ISPs block the standard SSH port(s) `22` & `2222`, have you checked reports of that being the case for yours?  Have you tried enabling another service to see if that works (easiest is probably Apache2 on `80` or `8080`)?  I know you said that you have the forwarding correct, but that would make sure other types of services work and it's specific to 22.

Comment: I forwarded port 2210 WAN to port in my local ethernet but still see the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to setting up NAT options in your router to point to your machine, if you don't do that you can not open a session from other computer which is not behind your router.